# Covid-19 virus day by day chart?

Tags: event-based-effects, covid-19

Do you know any website(s) where I could check how many COVID-19 cases Italy had 10 days ago?

Let me explain: We are travelling to the Dominican Republic at the end of this month with transfer in Germany (Frankfurt). At the start of this week, my country (Slovakia) banned all flights to and from Italy.

So I would like to check how many cases were there in Italy about 10 days ago, to maybe predict the future cases in Germany (possibility that all flights to Germany will be banned too). At this moment, our travel agency doesn't want to cancel our trip, and neither do we, because we would lose 80% of our money.

Comment: The data you are asking for are by far insufficient for the prediction you are trying to make.  Nobody knows how this will develop, and whatever the Italy situation was 10 days ago has virtually no use for modelling what it might do in Germany in the next 10 days.

Comment: @gerrit Yes maybe you are right, however I would like to check those data.

Comment: I already added and answer that might help you, but I'll comment anyway because I live in Germany. You won't get a clear prediction of what might happen in ten days simply because no one what will happen and how the government will handle this. Despite the amount of cases having increased by a lot in the last few days, nothing has changed. People still go out and live their lives. Moreover, the Italian lockdown happened out of the blue. It will probably be like that for any country as well.

Comment: @Calys Just FYI, much Arabian countries did place restrictions on Indian nationals even when the count was just 5, on which 3 recovered. And some didn't place any restrictions for Italy till now. So, its not always the infection count that drives the decision..

Comment: And Indian government tightened its border control and cancelled visas even when count was low. So, its almost entirely unpredictable. Policy decisions can come quickly without warning.

Comment: I'm an italian guy from red zone in Italy, don't underestimate the virus, don't wait your government measures, stay at home!

Comment: The oversimplified information one can extract from the various charts is that cases in Germany recently seem to double *about* every three days. That would mean a factor of *about* 10 for ten days. Of course this ignores many effects (e.g., potential good effects of cancelled major events)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: in other words, about a week to 10 days behind Italy.

Comment: Italy did better testing than other EU countries, so the situation in the rest of the EU is probably worse than what the numbers say

Comment: Note that if your trip involved a flight from Slovakia to Frankfurt, it'll get cancelled anyway, because Slovakia just decided to close all airports for all traffic.

Comment: Be aware that for Germany the statistics diverges widely between web pages. As of now we have in Germany according to worldometers 6215 active cases, John Hopkins 5813 cases, the RKI (german CDC) 4838 cases.

Comment: Also be aware that these day-to-day case numbers can be misleading, without information about how many tests on COVID-19 the countries do per day. Unfortunately many countries don't publish that number.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can check it [at Worldometers.info](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/italy/). There is plenty of info for each country in there.

[image: Worldometers.info chart of active COVID-19 cases in Italy through 9/Mar/2020]

Comment: That worldometers.info site is a fount of useful information, and not just about coronavirus.

Comment: @padd13ear It's nicely visualised, but is it true?

Comment: @choster scroll to the bottom of the page https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

Comment: @gerrit You could try validating the data against centrally-published data for your country of residence, for example. It certainly corresponds to official U.K. data https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-information-for-the-public The associated Twitter feed makes for interesting reading too https://mobile.twitter.com/guntramwolff/status/1236221132732329984

Comment: @Traveller Sure, I don't doubt it corresponds to the data WHO collects from member states, however, I don't trust the data reported by member states.  The UK government does not actually know how many people are carrying the virus without having symptoms.

Comment: @gerrit I guess that holds true world-wide, unfortunately. Although at least the UK appears to have been proactive in its testing early on, and to have a means of centrally collating data, unlike say the US, again judging only by the numbers reported which is all we poor mortals can do. It may well become all too obvious all too soon if member states have been massaging the figures :-(

Comment: @choster Within **Latest Updates** (after the country list), for each new report the original source is given as link.

Comment: @gerrit Do you have better data? Yeah, that's what I thought. Also, how would anyone know how many people carry the virus without symptoms? Do you propose to check 60+ million citizens in the UK? Will you be providing the 60 million testing kits? And the doctors?

Comment: Official repository from the Protezione Civile: https://github.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19

Comment: @gerrit Can you explain why this question is dangerous and should be deleted ?

Comment: Ah, a nice, beautiful exponential growth progression!

Comment: Just checked for Germany, the latest source they give for case numbers is a newspaper site. The very official federal site in Germany is https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Fallzahlen.html. Right now, these (RKI = German CDC) numbers are about 400 below what worldometer cites from the newspaper page. That may be due to the RKI web page  being behind the Länder (state, province) and Kreis (county) health authrity counts, though.

Comment: @undefined hu? Are you me?

Comment: @undefined maybe

Answer (score 40):

Have a look at the [Johns Hopkins Coronavirus dashboard](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html)

[image: Coronavoris Dashboard]

You can [access their database directly](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19) if you wish to do your own modelling on the projection of the virus.

There are also [daily situation reports](http://www.centerforhealthsecurity.org/resources/COVID-19/index.html) documenting progress of effects of the disease in relevant countries.

Answer (score 18):

The official WHO website is the best so far, it only shows clinically proven cases. However, it's a bit late sometimes.

https://www.who.int/redirect-pages/page/novel-coronavirus-(covid-19)-situation-dashboard

[image]

Comment: Interesting that these figures (live, not from the screenshot) disagreed with the John Hopkins dashboard in the other answer.

Comment: @Darren WHO is doing a very bad job with this pandemic. They seem to be deliberately underreporting and misinforming people.

Comment: @jwenting Note that JHU is using additional data from "media reports" (From the footer: "Confirmed cases include presumptive positive cases."), while WHO is only sourcing clinically proven cases. With all the media craze going around, i'm not sure if it is fair to consider WHO underreporting. Comparing countries, the mayor differences seem to occur in Germany and the US, no idea why that would be though.

Comment: I was wondering why the site wasn't loading, turns it out takes a while. Server must be busy.

Comment: @antipattern: for Germany, the Kreis (county) and Länder (state/province) health authorities both publish their official counts and send them to RKI (our CDC). RKI publishes only numbers they received via these official channels (says their web page, it also gives a time stamp for the counting deadline and a separate one for the web page update). The update of these various web pages (or press releases) is not synchronized, and if you just add up various sources, that may be inconsistent. Also, apparently some patients were counted twice at Kreis level which is then resolved at the Land level.

Comment: Right now, the WHO cites 1296 cases for Germany with time stamp March 11 16:00 CET. 1296 was the RKI (official federal) count of March 10 15:00 CET, published around March 10 18:00 CET. (Which is updated now to 1567 cases as of March 11 15:00 CET - published online at 18:10 CET) so the WHO is a day behind since they collected the numbers when they were already outdated and shortly before update. JHU lists 1908 cases which is closer to the 1966 on the newspaper page used by worldometer. The latter states that their daily numbers have deadline in the morning (not further specified) but also that

Comment: ... they accumulate from Länder and Kreis level. i.e. possibly before double counts were removed.

Comment: @antipattern WHO however is deliberately underreporting in order to make things appear less serious than they are. Now, this is in part because of countries themselves underreporting for the same reason, but those countries in turn report only cases identified using WHO's criteria which are laughably incorrect (e.g. Dutch RIVM only tests people who are both symptomatic, have been to or had direct contact with symptomatic people who have been to northern Italy or Wuhan, AND also test positive for influenza, when asymptomatic spread and community spread are a major infection vector).

Comment: @jwenting Im was simply pointing out where the difference comes from. When it comes to diagnostics, im probably unqualified to discuss.

Comment: @jwenting of course there's no possibility that the for-profit media are exploiting this event to maximize their profits from clickbait. That could never possibly happen, it must be a world government conspiracy.

Answer (score 9):

I kinda like [Mackuba.eu](https://mackuba.eu/corona/). It uses the data of the Johns Hopkins CSSE. And it creates nice graphs for every country.

[image: Chart of COVID-19 cases in Italy from Mackuba.eu]

Answer (score 8):

**Worldometer** is a good source for

- list of countries summary

  - with individual links to (at present) 9 countries

    - daily numbers and graphic results for different combinations

      - newly infected, recovered, deaths and comparisons
- Daily list of new reports

  - with a link to the original source

A **Coronavirus-Monitor** (from the Berlin Newspaper Morgenpost)

- based on **Johns Hopkins University CSSE** data
- showing Map results for **regional** areas (where available)

---

> Do you know any website(s) where I could check how many COVID-19 cases Italy had 10 days ago?

Goto [Germany](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/germany/), [Italy](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/italy/) or the [United States](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/), scroll down to the graphs:

- Total Coronavirus Cases in...
- Daily New Cases in...
- Active Cases in...
- Total Coronavirus Deaths in...
- Daily New Deaths in...
- Newly Infected vs. Newly Recovered in...
- Outcome of Cases (Recovery or Death) in...

Place your finger/mouse over the desired date:

- **Feb 21** (when the outbreak in Italy started)

[image: 2020-02-21: Germany 16 cases]
[image: 2020-02-21: Italy 21 cases]
[image: 2020-02-21: United States 35 cases]

The main total [Case Graphs](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries) page offers the same functionality.

---

**Sources**:

- [Coronavirus Cases: Statistics and Charts - Worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/coronavirus-cases)

  - [Case Graphs](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries)
  - [Confirmed Cases and Deaths by Country, Territory, or Conveyance](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries)
  - **[Latest Updates](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#news)**

    - sorted by day (latest first) and continent

      - in great detail per country, with link to each source
    - [Archive - February 2020 Coronavirus News Updates](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/feb-2020-news-updates-covid19/)
  - **Africa**

    - [Algeria](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/algeria/)
  - **Asia**

    - [China](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/china/)

      - [Hong Kong](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/china-hong-kong-sar/)
    - [Indonesia](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/indonesia/)
    - [Malaysia](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/malaysia/)
    - [Philippines](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/philippines/)
    - [South Korea](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/south-korea/)
  - **Australia**

    - [Australia](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/australia/)
  - **Europe**

    - [Austria](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/austria/)
    - [Belgium](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/belgium/)
    - [Denmark](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/denmark/)
    - [France](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/france/)
    - [Germany](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/germany/)
    - [Greece](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/greece/)
    - [Ireland](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/ireland/)
    - [Italy](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/italy/)
    - [Netherlands](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/netherlands/)
    - [Norway](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/norway/)
    - [Poland](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/poland/)
    - [Portugal](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/portugal/)
    - [Spain](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/spain/)
    - [Sweden](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/sweden/)
    - [Switzerland](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/switzerland/)
    - [United Kingdom](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/uk/)
  - **Middle East**

    - [Iraq](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/iraq/)
    - [Iran](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/iran/)
    - [Israel](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/israel/)
    - [Turkey](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/turkey/)
  - **North America**

    - [Canada](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/canada/)
    - [United States](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/)
  - **South America**

    - [Brasil](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/brazil/)
- [Coronavirus Symptoms (COVID-19)](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/coronavirus-symptoms/)
- [Coronavirus: Interactive Map Germany, Europe and World with numbers (in German)](https://interaktiv.morgenpost.de/corona-virus-karte-infektionen-deutschland-weltweit/?fbclid=IwAR04HlqzakGaNssQzbz4d8o8R3gz0C910U8tvfYlBT6P0lVJJvHfk9uS2rc)

  - [Coronavirus COVID-19 (2019-nCoV) - Johns Hopkins University](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6)

Answer (score 5):

Just adding the official graph of [Protezione Civile](http://www.protezionecivile.gov.it/en/risk-activities/health-risk/emergencies/coronavirus) on the same platform as John Hopkins one: http://opendatadpc.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/b0c68bce2cce478eaac82fe38d4138b1
Cases are broken down by region.

Data comes from official sources (Ministero della Salute). I recommend checking [their official website](http://www.salute.gov.it/nuovocoronavirus) too for official news (italian only).

Comment: Official github repository with the data: https://github.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19

Comment: I hope they realise that "Incremento giornaliero degli attualmente positivi" (daily change in currently positive) is a very misleading metric to be looking at. Because this is new cases minus recoveries and deaths.

They should be focusing on how many new cases there are if they want to gauge how fast the virus is spreading. 

If someone dies it will decrease the number ""Incremento giornaliero degli attualmente positivi" but it doesn't mean the virus is spreading slower.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know of a website publishing historic day-by-day data, but this one https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries includes a detailed historic commentary on the figures so you could probably work out what you are looking for based on the data as at today and tracking back through the commentary to the date you’re interested in.

However, I agree with @Gerrit - it is impossible to draw any meaningful conclusions at all from such an exercise. There are too many variables eg population tested, date when testing began in Germany and on what basis etc.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted the answer above as he was the first and you provided the same website. And thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Calys Sheer speculation, but countries with a land border with Italy might be more likely to introduce a travel ban sooner than those without. So you could consider rerouting via an airport outside the worst-hit countries. But quantifying what ‘more likely’ might mean is of course impossible.

Answer (score 4):

I also like this blog post with realtime charts about the corona virus:

- https://blog.datawrapper.de/coronaviruscharts/#column-chart-Italy
- https://blog.datawrapper.de/coronaviruscharts/#column-chart-Germany

P.S.: I'm not affiliated with this company.

Answer (score 1):

Computer science students build coronavirus tracking website TrackCorona - Live Map: https://www.trackcorona.live/map