# After flight rescheduled infant is >2 years old. Do I need to buy a new ticket?

Tags: air-travel, children, cancellations, return-tickets

I have a two-way airline ticket for an infant with no separate seat. The airline canceled flight back and rescheduled tickets for a new date.

But on this new date, an infant is already 2 years old, so the airline wants me to buy a new ticket for her.

The rescheduling happened not because of us. Are there any rules for cases like this?

UPD. The airline company is Turkish Airlines.
The reason for flight cancelation is the COVID crisis and governments closing borders. Though borders were officially reopened 2 weeks before the child's 2nd birthday, so after that it was a company's decision. It seems to be a collision.

Comment: What is the airline, and how long is the date difference?

Comment: Related, and possibly answers your question:  [Refunding the ticket, not the value of the ticket](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157557/refunding-the-ticket-not-the-value-of-the-ticket)

Comment: @KateGregory It's Turkish Airlines. Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

I can empathize with your plight. Logic and common sense would say that you complied with the letter and the spirit of the airline rules when purchasing the ticket. Through no fault of your own, you will be out of compliance with those requirements after the rescheduling of the flight. And, there is no Appreciable difference between an average 23 month old infant and an average 25 month old toddler. There’s even less of a difference between a 729 day old child and a 731 day old child. Logic and common sense would say that the airline should make accommodations for you to be able to hold your daughter.

Unfortunately, in the US, there are also federal regulations with which you must consider and the airline is required to ensure you comply. Title 14 of the Code of Federal Regulations (CFR) Part 91.107(a)(e)(i) States the following:

> **§91.107 Use of safety belts, shoulder harnesses, and child restraint systems.**
> (i) Be held by an adult who is occupying an approved seat or berth, provided that the person being held has not reached his or her second birthday and does not occupy or use any restraining device;

The aviation authorities of other countries probably have similar regulations.

Check with the headquarters of the airline. I don’t see how they are obligated to provide a free seat for your child. But, good customer service would dictate that they accommodate or compensate you somehow while staying in compliance with federal regulations. After all, the reschedule of your flight was their fault and not yours.

Comment: I think the OP could reasonably request the airline provide, as compensation, the extra cost due to their decision to reschedule.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan if they rescheduled because of the pandemic, I dont think the airline has any obligation to offer anything.

Comment: @Moo I agree there is no obligation. I was suggesting making a request, not a demand.

Comment: The cancelation reason was the pandemic and borders closing. Though borders reopened 2 weeks before the child's birthday and the airline canceled the flight after borders opening. So I guess it's kind of collision. Updated the question

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes, I will request for compensation, just curious if any regulations exist to support the request